# Given $x,y$ find $P$ Housholder such that $Px=y.$

Tags: matrices

Let $x, y$ be non zero vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Find a Housholder matrix $P$ such that $Px=y$.

Attempt. I need to find a vector $u$ such that $x-2uu^\star x/ u^\star u$ is a multiple of $y.$

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Try thinking about this geometrically: a Householder matrix represents a reflection about a hyperplane through the origin.

Comment: This is not possible in general. A Householder transformation is unitary, hence we need $\|x\|=\|y\|$.